# Proof of the Theorem of the Cube

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, line-bundles

I am trying to understand the proof of the Theorem 2.5 [here](https://www.math.ru.nl/%7Ebmoonen/BookAV/LineBund.pdf)(Theorem of the Cube).

It is required to prove that an invertible sheaf on $X\times Y\times Z$ is trivial when the restrictions to $\left \{ x \right \}\times Y\times Z,X\times \left \{ y \right \}\times Z,X\times Y\times \left \{ z \right \}$  are trivial. $X,Y, Z$ are complete varieties(integral) over $k$ and $x\in X(k),y\in Y(k), z\in Z(k)$.[$Z$ may be taken as only a connected scheme]

The proof follows from David Mumford's book "Abelian Varieties". I understood most of the proof but not the last part where it is proved that $H^1(X\times Y,O_{X\times Y})=0$

> The obstruction for lifting s to a global section of $L_2$ is an element $ξ ∈ H^1(X × Y,O_{X×Y} )$
> We know that the restrictions of $L_2$ to ${x} × Y × Z_2$ and to $X × {y} × Z_2$ are trivial. Writing $i_1 = (id_X, y): X→ X × Y\  and\  i_2 = (x, id_Y ): Y→ X × Y$ , this means that ξ has trivial image
> under $i_1^{*}: H^1(X ×Y,O_{X×Y} ) → H^1(X, O_X) $ and under $i_2^{*}: H^1(X ×Y,O_{X×Y} ) → H^1(Y, O_Y)$.

I am missing something and cannot figure out how the images in $H^1(X, O_X),H^1(Y, O_Y)$ are $0$. Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the definition of $\xi$ and $s$?

Comment: ${Z}'$ is the maximal closed subscheme of $Z$ on which the restriction of L to $X\times Y\times Z'$ is trivial. To prove the result we need to show ${Z}'$ is open (connectedness will show ${Z}'$=$Z$. Let $I$ be a germ of the coherent sheaf of ideal defining ${Z}'$, and it will suffice to prove $I$=0, $\mathfrak{M}$ is the maximal ideal of the germ.

Comment: Then form the ideals $a_1=(I,\mathfrak{M}), a_2$, such that $dim_k(a_1/a_2)=1$ and $Z_1,Z_2$ the corresponding closed subschemes. $L_i$ is the restriction of $L$ to $X\times Y\times Z_i$. It was then proved that the natural map $\Gamma(L_2)\rightarrow \Gamma(L_1)$ needs to be shown surjective. So $s$ is a global section of $L_1$, which needs a lift in $L_2$, and $\xi$ is an element of $H^1(X\times Y, O_{X\times Y} )$ which needs to be shown $0$.

Comment: @Mindlack, I have put in two comments the summary of the proof, more details can be found in the link given.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn’t seen the link. The idea is that the image of $\xi$ into $H^1(X,O_X)$ (by the inclusion $X \subset X \times \{y\} \subset X \times Y$) is the obstruction to lifting $s_{|X \times \{y\} \times  Z_1}$ to a section of $L_{|X \times \{y\} \times Z_2}$. But as this bundle is trivial, the section can be lifted (see the paragraph above) so the obstruction vanishes.

Comment: @Mindlack Thanks, that was a small thing I missed.